# Compiling Tilde text editor on MacOS

Tags: macos, compilation

I'm trying to compile The Tilde Text Editor under MacOS 10.12.2 (Sierra) with no previous experience in compiling (so please correct me on anything) and I'm getting this error:

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [src/libt3window.la] Error 1`

Steps so far (some are redundant):

- Install homebrew, Xcode
- `brew install cmake`
- `brew install gettext`
- `brew link --force gettext`
- `brew install autoconf` (?)
- `brew install automake` (?)
- `brew install libtool`
- `brew install pkg-config`
- `brew install libunistring`
- `brew install libsigc++`
- build [libtranscript](http://os.ghalkes.nl/libtranscript.html) from source by changing this from **configure**:

`[ -z "${LIBTOOL}" ] && LIBTOOL="libtool"`

to this:

`[ -z "${LIBTOOL}" ] && LIBTOOL="glibtool"`

and this in **Makefile.in**

`LIBTOOL=libtool`

to this:

`LIBTOOL=glibtool`

then `./configure && make && sudo make install`

- build [libt3window](http://os.ghalkes.nl/t3/libt3window.html) from source by changing **configure** and **Makefile.in** like with libtranscript, then `./configure && make`. So with `make` the error shows up:

`duplicate symbol __t3_modifier_hack in:
    src/.libs/window.o
    src/.libs/terminal_init.o
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [src/libt3window.la] Error 1`

And one more question: how to I remove everything I installed?

Comment: Did you succeed? If you did would you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in libt3window (a missing "extern" in the declaration of the _t3_modifier_hack variable). This is fixed in version 0.2.6 of libt3window.

Comment: Thank you! libt3window compiled, but you may need to change the link [here](https://os.ghalkes.nl/t3/libt3window.html) to the new version, it's pointing to an old one. I have a problem with the final step now.

New error while compiling Tilde itself:

```
Creating Makefile
[CXX] src/main.cc
src/main.cc:747:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LC_ALL'
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

I commented out `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` in **main.cc**, it compiled and Tilde is running seemingly fine, but I'm getting `65628 segmentation fault tilde` message when trying to save files.